# How to insert amazon associate ad widget into website

Tags: javascript, html, gatsby, amazon-product-api

[Github Repo](https://github.com/stackoverflowsam93/amazon-assoc-problem) (With dummy id(which works))

**Update:** It looks like the problem may be that the ad widget I am trying to use requires flash. There are other Amazon ads I am able to display(view github repo), but it looks like some of the more specific widgets may be using flash. I figure that using flash widgets may be a bad idea, but some of the widgets recommended to me on the Amazon Associate website may only be possible using flash.

---

I am trying to insert the [deals widget](https://associates.amazon.ca/home/widgets/Amazon-Deals-Widget). I select that I want a sidebar which is `160x400`(each of the inner divs in my example is about `520x100`). When I click "Add to my webpage" they give me the following popup window so I copy and paste that code into my html file.

[image]

I don't know exactly where to put it, so I've tried multiple places which include the head, the body, and inside the innerDiv on the left as shown in the code snippet below. None of these attempts have made the widget show.

**Note:** The text `my-amazon-associate-id` is used in replacement for my actual amazon associate id, I don't the link can work because of this but I had to replace it to abide by Amazon's policies.

```css
#container{
    display: flex;
    height: 1000px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.innerDiv{
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test Webpage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
  <SCRIPT charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=CA&ID=V20070822%2FCA%my-amazon-associate-id%2F8009%2F4246f29c-6400-4a95-9cdd-994f55f4a2dc&Operation=GetScriptTemplate"> </SCRIPT> <NOSCRIPT><A rel="nofollow" HREF="//ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=CA&ID=V20070822%2FCA%my-amazon-associate-id%2F8009%2F4246f29c-6400-4a95-9cdd-994f55f4a2dc&Operation=NoScript">Amazon.ca Widgets</A></NOSCRIPT>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class='innerDiv'>
      <SCRIPT charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=CA&ID=V20070822%2FCA%my-amazon-associate-id%2F8009%2F4246f29c-6400-4a95-9cdd-994f55f4a2dc&Operation=GetScriptTemplate"> </SCRIPT> <NOSCRIPT><A rel="nofollow" HREF="//ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=CA&ID=V20070822%2FCA%my-amazon-associate-id%2F8009%2F4246f29c-6400-4a95-9cdd-994f55f4a2dc&Operation=NoScript">Amazon.ca Widgets</A></NOSCRIPT>
    </div>
    <div class='innerDiv'>
      Hello World
    </div>
    <div class='innerDiv'>
      World
    </div>
  </div>
  <SCRIPT charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=CA&ID=V20070822%2FCA%my-amazon-associate-id%2F8009%2F4246f29c-6400-4a95-9cdd-994f55f4a2dc&Operation=GetScriptTemplate"> </SCRIPT> <NOSCRIPT><A rel="nofollow" HREF="//ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=CA&ID=V20070822%2FCA%my-amazon-associate-id%2F8009%2F4246f29c-6400-4a95-9cdd-994f55f4a2dc&Operation=NoScript">Amazon.ca Widgets</A></NOSCRIPT>
</body>
</html>
```

---

There must be something really simple that I don't know about because this doesn't seem that hard, do not assume I have any common knowledge in this subject.

Comment: Yes, the given code doesn't work due to `my-amazon-associate-id`, the result is empty javascript

Comment: @DanieleRicci I'm pretty sure you can get banned for posting your real id with the link on places that aren't intended for it so I can't post it. If I replace `my-amazon-associate-id` with the real id though the result is the same. For people willing to put it effort, I don't think it takes long to create an account and then receive your own id.

Comment: @DanieleRicci Although I just realized that I could possibly create a dummy account

Comment: With my comment I would asking you your private infos, was just to let you know. Please check my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** You could try this:

```
<iframe src="/other_page_in_my_site.html"></iframe>
```

and fill `/other_page_in_my_site.html` with following content:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <SCRIPT charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=CA&ID=V20070822%2FCA%my-amazon-associate-id%2F8009%2F4246f29c-6400-4a95-9cdd-994f55f4a2dc&Operation=GetScriptTemplate"> </SCRIPT> <NOSCRIPT><A rel="nofollow" HREF="//ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=CA&ID=V20070822%2FCA%my-amazon-associate-id%2F8009%2F4246f29c-6400-4a95-9cdd-994f55f4a2dc&Operation=NoScript">Amazon.ca Widgets</A></NOSCRIPT>
 </body>
</html>
```

Pay attention to use the code from amazon site to get the real code.

Another possible source of problem could be having disabled flash in your browser.

Another one possible source of problem could it be having AD blockers enabled.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So when I do this there is an empty iframe in my browser. When I inspect the code I see `<iframe class=“innerDiv”>
 #document
 <html>
  <head></head>
  <body class=“vac-initialized”></body>
 </html>
</iframe>`. I tried to copy and paste this code into the comment(the code you see in this comment is manually typed) but when I c&p it pastes code that looks identical to your answer. I don't know why that is but like I said the iframe is empty. Does it make a difference if I'm opening the page locally instead of on the actual domain?

Comment: I'm still getting the same results unfortunately, except that now I can actually see the right code in the browser inspector. I uploaded the project to [this Github repo](https://github.com/stackoverflowsam93/amazon-assoc-problem), it has the actual id. I uninstalled adblocker, I'm using firefox, same results on chrome. My firefox has a plugin called Shockwave flash(do these ads actually use Flash? Isn't flash unsupported in 6 months?)

Comment: I don't know if flash is deprecated (never interested in it), but yes, this widget uses flash. Do you mind to change the widget to add to your site before spending other time on it?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by change the widget to add? What's in the Github is everything I know how to do. I uploaded a screenshot of the flashplugin to the github

Comment: I mean go to amazon website and choose another widget to add to your website, a widget which doesn't use flash; if flash is really deprecated I think amazon already developed other widgets will not going to break in 6 months.

Comment: Yes I'm able to display the prime day ads, but I was having trouble with this one and I think some other ones that display a specific product. I'll have to post details on those in the morning though. And about flash being deprecated, I just know that chrome tells me it's no longer supporting flash starting at the end of 2020. I think it told me that because I had some flash plugin that I installed to use this really old website. I don't have the plugin anymore, but my firefox has a flash plugin apparently

Comment: If you test the repos from local you have to add the protocol to the script: change `src="//` with `src="https://` than it works, but would change the widget as this one uses flash and I'm afraid many users wont see it

Comment: I updated with 2 ads on the website, one works(the prime one), and the other doesn't(the one you're saying is flash), I'm using https now. How do you know it's flash? How can I check on my computer to see if it's because it's flash that it's not working? Do you know how to search for non flash widgets?

Comment: I know the first one (the one on left side of the page) is flash because chrome asked me to enable flash in order to let me see the content, then, inspecting I saw the tag `<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash ...>`. Inspecting the second (the one on the right side of the page) you can see it is not using flash. About how to check if it is flash making the first one not working, honestly I would simply save time dropping the flash widget.

Comment: Have you read my last comment @Sam ? What about to use the one on the right? The one which doesn't use flash

Comment: I just read it. I'm going to leave my question open until the bounty in case someone sees it and feels they can offer more insight. I don't know why Amazon listed that flash widget as a possibility but I would like to try to include widgets which show things such as "Deals" or other helpful things, instead of just displaying a bunch of ads for amazon prime. I think I may have other ad networks that I'm trying to use that might also be using flash. Flash is probably a bad idea, but I want to see what other people say.

Comment: It sounds reasonable. Good luck @Sam !

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container{
    display: flex;
    height: 1000px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.innerDiv{
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test Webpage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
  <SCRIPT charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=CA&ID=V20070822%2FCA%my-amazon-associate-id%2F8009%2F4246f29c-6400-4a95-9cdd-994f55f4a2dc&Operation=GetScriptTemplate"> </SCRIPT> <NOSCRIPT><A rel="nofollow" HREF="//ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=CA&ID=V20070822%2FCA%my-amazon-associate-id%2F8009%2F4246f29c-6400-4a95-9cdd-994f55f4a2dc&Operation=NoScript">Amazon.ca Widgets</A></NOSCRIPT>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class='innerDiv'>
      <SCRIPT charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=CA&ID=V20070822%2FCA%my-amazon-associate-id%2F8009%2F4246f29c-6400-4a95-9cdd-994f55f4a2dc&Operation=GetScriptTemplate"> </SCRIPT> <NOSCRIPT><A rel="nofollow" HREF="//ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=CA&ID=V20070822%2FCA%my-amazon-associate-id%2F8009%2F4246f29c-6400-4a95-9cdd-994f55f4a2dc&Operation=NoScript">Amazon.ca Widgets</A></NOSCRIPT>
    </div>
    <div class='innerDiv'>
      Hello World
    </div>
    <div class='innerDiv'>
      World
    </div>
  </div>
  <SCRIPT charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=CA&ID=V20070822%2FCA%my-amazon-associate-id%2F8009%2F4246f29c-6400-4a95-9cdd-994f55f4a2dc&Operation=GetScriptTemplate"> </SCRIPT> <NOSCRIPT><A rel="nofollow" HREF="//ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=CA&ID=V20070822%2FCA%my-amazon-associate-id%2F8009%2F4246f29c-6400-4a95-9cdd-994f55f4a2dc&Operation=NoScript">Amazon.ca Widgets</A></NOSCRIPT>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).